# Pointer to nth element of multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am wondering how to access the nth element of a multi dimensional array using a pointer to that array.

Assume I have the following

```
struct Struct_B
{
    bool asdf;
};

struct Struct_A
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    Struct_B *ptr;
};

typedef Struct_A new_typedef[10][20][30];

new_typedef Array;

// Set values within Array, including correctly setting ptr variable

// Within debugger, Array_ptr contains the correct data, identical to Array, as it should.
new_typedef* Array_ptr = &Array;

for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for ( int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 30; k++) {
            // Crashes on this conditional'
            // Within debugger, asdf is in some random location in memory, implying I am not accessing it correctly.
            // Same problem exists if I attempt to access X or Y
            if ( (*Array_ptr)[i][j][k].ptr->asdf) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to dereference the pointer first:

```
(*Array_ptr)[i][j][k].X = 5;
```

---

**Edit:**

> `if ( (*Array_ptr)[i][j][k].ptr->asdf)` crashes

That's because `.ptr` is uninitialzied.

Comment: That is what I initially had actually. I updated my first example a bit more. In the debugger, Array_ptr correctly contains all the data seen in Array. However, I dont think I am accessing it correctly, because looking at the conditional that it crashes on within the debugger produces some random location in memory.

Comment: @halexh It crashes because `.ptr` is uninitialized and points to a random location.

Comment: @halexh Also, you shouldn't make significant changes to the code in your question after posting. It invalidates existing answers (like this one).

Comment: Sorry about that - wasnt sure how else to easily convey responses besides just updating the original